# Exporting into a single large CSV from MySQL Workbench into the client machine without viewing it on GUI?

Tags: mysql-workbench

After going through similar questions on Stackoverflow, I am unable to find a method where I could export a large CSV file from a query made in MySQL workbench (v 5.2).

The query is about 4 million rows, 8 columns (comes to about 300Mb when exported as a csv file).

Currently I load the entire rows (have see it in the GUI) and use the export option. This makes my machine crash most of the time)

My constraints are:
I am not looking for a solution via bash terminal.
I need to export it to the client machine and not the database server.

Is this drawback of MySQL Workbench?
How do I not see it in GUI but yet export all the rows into a single file?

There is a similar question I found, but the answers dont meet the constraints I have:
" Exporting query results in MySQL Workbench beyond 1000 records "

Thanks.

Comment: Also if your host has installed phpmyadmin , then it can handle it, just use export option after you run your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to export to CSV you first have to load all that data, which is a lot to have in a GUI. many controls are simply no made to carry that much data. So your best bet is to avoid GUI as much as possible.

One way could be to run your query outputting to a text window (see Query menu). This is not CSV but at least should work. You can then try to copy out the text into a spreadsheet and convert it to CSV.

If that is too much work try limiting your rows into ranges, say 1 million each, using the LIMIT clause on your query. Lower the size until you have one that can be handled by MySQL Workbench. You will get n CSV files you have to concatenate later. A small application or (depending on your OS) a system tool should be able to strip headers and concatenate the files into one.